# Jasmine spyOn not working

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am fairly new to Jasmine, and I have to test a few function calls:

**JS CODE**

```js
 object1 = {

    function1: function() {
       // object1.function2 is a callback
       object2.someFunction("called", object1.function2)
    },

    function2:  function() {
       // code to do stuff
    }

 }
```

**TEST CODE**

```js
describe("test suite", function(){ 
     it("test1", function(){ 
          spyOn(object1, "function2");
          object1.function1();
          expect(object1.function2).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });
});
```

I've tried the above but it fails, and says "Expected spy function2 to have been called". Can somebody help me out with this ? Thanks

Comment: do you have a unit test that proves that object2.someFunction eventually calls the callback?

UNIT test should test the UNIT.  So, you should test that object2.someFunction calls the callback it is passed and then you would write a test to verify that function1 calls object2.someFunction

of course, for that to work you'll need to pass object2 to object1 as a parameter either to function() or to the object1 constructor. (Dependency injection)

Comment: @DaveBush object2 is a global object, so there shouldn't be a dependency injection issue, and I am pretty sure that object2.someFunction calls the callback. However it would be helpful if you could tell me how to test that as well.

Comment: @DaveBush Thanks, I noticed that object2.someFunction doesn't call the callback. I thought I was going wrong with the way I was using spyOn.

Comment: Is the callback asyncronous ?

Comment: @BorisCharpentier Yes, object2.someFunction includes an ajax call.

Comment: Check the "done" function in jasmine, asynchronous test are not working out of the box (and can't). You have to tell jasmine when your async task is finished and it will wait for it. You may have some refactoring to do.

Answer (score 9):

You can rewrite the test as follows

```js
describe("test suite", function(){ 
     it("test1", function(done){ 
          spyOn(object1, "function2");
          object1.function1();
          setTimeout(function() {
              expect(object1.function2).toHaveBeenCalled();
              done();
          });
     });
});
```

Your test code needs to have asynchronous testing since the callback will never be called immediately. You can add another async call which will be placed after your `object1.function2` in the call stack and by the time the function inside `setTimeout` is executed it would have already called the `object1.function2` and once assertion is made you can end the async test by calling `done()`.